# Listview with custom adapter having two spinners inside

Tags: android, android-listview, android-spinner

i want to create a list view with custom adapter. This I did successfully. In the list I have three views:

- textview
- spinner1
- spinner2

Text view is just acting like a label.
What I am trying to accomplish is I want to change the choices available in spinner2 whenever anything in spinner 1 is selected. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788047/spinner-selection-defines-choices-for-another-spinner) but the content of spinner2 does not change. Please help me out.

Comment: do you update your listview after updating the contents of spinner?

Comment: i don't know how to do that either.

Comment: Refresh your adapter , my adding logs make sure that the right content is set in spinner2 when you make change in spinner1 . If the content is changed , refresh the UI.

Comment: after changing your spinner do `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged(); `