# Implement multiple spinners with json data in Android

Tags: android, json, android-spinner

I want to create a form screen with 4 or 5 spinners with different levels, should be like this:

University: Universidade do Minho 
Campus: Azurém 
Building: Bloco B 
<strike>Floor: 1</strike> 

Room: LID 1

This data is stored in my database and I access it through my web service..
The main problem is that all spinners are dependent to each other and I don't know how to implement it.. I've trying to do something based on this answer [ [spinner selection defines choices for another spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788047/spinner-selection-defines-choices-for-another-spinner) ]

But my case is different and more complex..  I don't know as well if I should get all data once or if I should make queries according to what I'm selecting.

**Edit:**
   I made some changes and this is a sample of what I'm getting from my web service..

```
{
    "campuses":[
        {
            "id": "8",
            "name": "Azurém",
            "buildings": [
                {
                    "id": "10",
                    "name": "Bloco B"
                },
                {
                    "id": "11",
                    "name": "Bloco C"
                },
                {
                    "id": "12",
                    "name": "Escola de Ciências"
                },
                {
                    "id": "13",
                    "name": "Escola de Engenharia",
                    "rooms": [
                        {
                            "id": "14",
                            "name": "LID 1",
                            "floor": "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "15",
                            "name": "LID 3",
                            "floor": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "9",
            "name": "Gualtar"
        }
    ]
  }
```

<strike>My problem now is in the client side (android)..</strike> I think I've an idea how to do it, but suggestions are always welcome :)

**New Edit:** The current screen looks like this -> [Location Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb876.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean all spinners are dependent on each other? If you select "University 1" then only certain options are available for the rest of the categories?

Comment: Yes. For example, the campus "Azurém" is only at the university "Universidade do Minho" and LID 1 is just on "Azurém" campus and so on..Each campus has their own buildings..

And after I make this, I will have to add an option in some spinners like "Other room.." and when this option is selected has to fire some EditText so that the user can enter a new Room (in this case)..

Answer (score 0):

So, each one of those categories is a different spinner (i.e. University is one, Campus is another, etc...)?

Your webservice can return each university as a JSON object and all of them within the encapsulating object. You can map this to a Java object and then make the magic happen when something is selected! Like this:

```
 {
   "universities": {
        "univ1" : [
            "campuses" : {
                "campus1", "campus2"
            }, 
            "buildings" : {
                "building1", "building2"
            },
            "floors" : {
                "floor1", "floor2"
            },
            "rooms" : {
                "room1", "room2"
            }
        ],
        "univ2" : [
            "campuses" : {
                "campus1", "campus2"
            }, 
            "buildings" : {
                "building1", "building2"
            },
            "floors" : {
                "floor1", "floor2"
            },
            "rooms" : {
                "room1", "room2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Of course if you're data set is really large then you might be better off querying for universities first and forcing the user to select that first before querying for the rest of the data.

Comment: I made some changes in my post.. Thank you for your help, but all categories are linked to each other.. What do you think about my approach?

Comment: Looks pretty good. How do you know which university a campus is tied to?

Comment: For this project i just need to specify one university.. In the post I put University field for better understanding..
I'm developing a positioning system based on wifi fingerprint for my university, but I'll have to accept checkins from outside the university, for that case I'm implementing another similiar screen but with Country, city and place..

Comment: I think your approach is pretty good! It'll be pretty easy to load up the spinners from that JSON object that you get back! Again, if you have a lot of different campuses then you might consider forcing the user to choose that first and then executing another query for the rest of the data...

Comment: After I do some testing I'll see if that is necessary ;) You can see how the screen looks now :)